# datepicker not working IE10 in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

if i select date using the datepicker from chrome then it display ng-valid.but in IE 10 it always showing invalid...but if user enters date manually input type then show valid.

I'm using

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker

Comment: it would help if you would tell us which date picker is not working and maybe sharing a bit of your code with an example.

Comment: thnx for reply toskv.....it's same as Jquery date picker.i can also set value using $('#id').datepicker('setdate',2/2/1989) ,it's working fine but i dn't know why it's always show input type as ng-invalid.